# Adding Attention on top of simple LSTM layer in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, attention-model

I have a simple network of one LSTM and two Dense layers as such:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(20, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error')
```

It is training on data with 3 inputs (normalized 0 to 1.0) and 1 output (binary) for the purpose of classification. The data is time series data where there is a relation between time steps.

```
    var1(t)   var2(t)   var3(t)  var4(t)
0  0.448850  0.503847  0.498571      0.0
1  0.450992  0.503480  0.501215      0.0
2  0.451011  0.506655  0.503049      0.0
```

The model is trained as such:

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=2800, batch_size=40, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
model.summary()
```

Giving the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 20)                1920      
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 20)                420       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 21        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,361
Trainable params: 2,361
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model works reasonably well. Now I am trying to replace the Dense(20) layer with an Attention layer. All the examples, tutorials, etc. online (including the TF docs) are for seq2seq models with an embedding layer at the input layer. I understand the seq2seq implementations in TF v1.x but I cannot find any documentation for what I am trying to do. I believe in the new API (v2.0) I need to do something like this:

```
lstm = layers.LSTM(20, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True)
lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm)
attention = layers.Attention() # this does not work

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(lstm)
model.add(attention)
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error')
```

And of course I get the error "*Attention layer must be called on a list of inputs, namely [query, value] or [query, value, key]*"

I do not understand the solution to this in version (2.0) and for this case (time series data with fixed length input). Any ideas on adding attention to this type of problem is welcome.

Comment: here a simple solution to add attention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948332/how-to-add-attention-layer-to-a-bi-lstm/62949137#62949137

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I eventually found two answers to the problem, both from libraries on pypi.org. The first is [self-attention](https://pypi.org/project/keras-self-attention/) and can be implemented with Keras (the pre TF 2.0 integrated version of Keras) as follows...

```
        model = keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(cfg.LSTM, input_shape=(cfg.TIMESTEPS,
                  cfg.FEATURES),
                  return_sequences=True))
        model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_width=cfg.ATTNWIDTH,
                attention_type=SeqSelfAttention.ATTENTION_TYPE_MUL,
                attention_activation='softmax',
                name='Attention'))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(cfg.DENSE))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(cfg.OUTPUT, activation='sigmoid'))
```

The second way to do it is a [more general solution](https://pypi.org/project/attention/) that works with the post TF 2.0 integrated Keras as follows...

```
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.LSTM(cfg.LSTM, input_shape=(cfg.SEQUENCES,
                  train_X.shape[2]),
                  return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Attention(name='attention_weight'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(train_Y.shape[2], activation='sigmoid'))
```

They each behave a little different, and produce very different results. The self-attention library reduces the dimensions from 3 to 2 and when predicting you get a prediction per input vector. The general attention mechanism maintains the 3D data and outputs 3D, and when predicting you only get a prediction per batch. You can solve this by reshaping your prediction data to have batch sizes of 1 if you want predictions per input vector.

As for results, the self-attention did produce superior results to LSTM alone, but not better than other enhancements such as dropout or more dense, layers, etc. The general attention does not seem to add any benefit to an LSTM model and in many cases makes things worse, but I'm still investigating.

In any case, it can be done, but so far it's dubious if it should be done.

Comment: Thanks for this post and the corresponding answer. I am facing the same issue and tried the second generalized solution. However, it is giving me a completely different sort of error now -- IndexError: list index out of range [pointing to the line where I added the attention layer]. I would like to add that the layer before the attention layer is an LSTM layer and the layer following the attention layer is a dense layer (n_outputs, activation = 'softmax'). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.